# How to access deeply nested data from json in swift?

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I have a problem with getting to "WaznyDo": "2021-09-18"
Xcode returns errors when trying to traverse the data model

```
{
    "lastUpdate": "2021-08-31 06:40:35",
    "karty": {
        "0000985766": {
            "bilety": [
                {
                    "Taryfa": [
                        "Miesiczny",
                        " wacny we wszystkie dni tygodnia",
                        " ulgowy",
                        " imienny"
                                ],
                    "Strefa": "Miasto Gdask",
                    "WaznyDo": "2021-09-18"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried every decoder on the internet but it didn't help

Comment: And please learn to tell where errors come from: is it a compiler error? Can you launch your app? Does it crash? Does it misbehave? What does it do and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: So what is your data model?

Comment: "every decoder on the internet"?  Really?  Especiaslly as the only one you will need is Swift's  JSONDecoder.  If you want help you need to show what you've attempted (i.e. the code and data model), what the error is, and where it occurs.

Comment: You don't show your code.  You don't show the exact error message you have.  So what exactly is your topic about?  Just give me code?

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io

Answer (score 1):

Instead of destructive comments – here's a solution:

You need some structs to model the structure of your JSON data:

```
struct AllData: Codable {
    let lastUpdate: String
    let karty: Karty
}

struct Karty: Codable {
    let a0000985766: A0000985766
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a0000985766 = "0000985766"
    }
}

struct A0000985766: Codable {
    let bilety: [Bilety]
}

struct Bilety: Codable {
    let taryfa: [String]
    let strefa, waznyDo: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case taryfa = "Taryfa"
        case strefa = "Strefa"
        case waznyDo = "WaznyDo"
    }
}
```

If you store your JSON data in a file called "data.json" and put it in some folder inside your app, you can retrieve it via url:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")
```

Now here's a simple view controller printing out your desired data:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var allData: AllData!
    // URL of JSON file
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        do {
            allData = try JSONDecoder().decode(AllData.self, from: Data(contentsOf: url!))
        } catch {
            print("json error when trying to serialize")
        }
        
        
        // Output results, for example:
        print(allData!.lastUpdate)                          // 2021-08-31 06:40:35
        print(allData!.karty.a0000985766.bilety[0].waznyDo)  // 2021-09-18
    }
}
```